# how to stop swabbing one fragment in FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

hi every one I'm working on android application that will contain a set for fragments, an the problem I need to make the fragment 1 working only by the menu and not working by finger swab.

and this is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fm));
    }



}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
{
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("MASAFA", "get item is called " + i);
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (i == 0)
        {
            fragment = new FragmentA();
        }
        if (i == 1)
        {
            fragment = new FragmentB();
        }
        if (i == 2)
        {
            fragment = new FragmentC();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("MASAFA", "get count is called");
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (position == 0)
        {
            return "Tab 0";
        }
        if (position == 1)
        {
            return "Tab 1";
        }
        if (position == 2)
        {
            return "Tab 2";
        }
        return null;    
    }

}
```

Comment: @tyczj I suppose it's "swiping". Nevertheless, it doesn't change the fact that the question is quite unclear... Voting to close.

Comment: I mean moving fragment by finger "by touching"